# How is では used under these contexts?

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-は, particle-で

I'm trying to understand a specific uses of で + は particle, and I would like a more detailed explanation of how it's used.

I referred to these 3 resources: [デジタル大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF/#je-51731) [Weblio](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF) [コトバンク](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF-576596)

Namely, there are 2 uses that I can't understand completely.

---

The first use:

From [デジタル大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF/#je-51731)

> 4 〔…だったら〕
>
> 今から**では**遅過ぎる It's too late now.

From [Weblio](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF)

> 4 〈…であっては, …であったら〉
>
> これ**では**困ります. This won't do.

I assume these two sites refer to the same usage.

I'm not confident if this では can be a complete replacement for だったら,

In this case doesn't だったら mean "if" or "when"?

> 暇**だったら**、遊びに行くよ。If you're free let's go play.
>
> 暇**では**、遊びに行くよ。If you're free let's go play. (I'm not sure if this is grammatical)

I'd like more clarification on how to use では in this context.

---

The second use:

From [デジタル大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF/#je-51731)

> 〔…から判断すると〕
>
> あの顔付き**では**失敗したらしいね Judging from the look on his face, I'm afraid he has failed.

From [Weblio](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF)

> 〈…から判断すると〉
>
> 彼の態度**では**, きっと仕事を辞めると思います. Judging from his behavior, I am quite sure
>   that he will quit his job.

From [コトバンク](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF-576596)

> 《断定の助動詞「だ」の連用形＋係助詞「は」》判断の前提を表す。…であるとすれば。…だと。「雨**では**中止になる」「彼**では**だれも承知しないだろう」

Reading the definitions, it seems that から判断すると can replace では in this context.

But according to Japanese people I asked, it sounds unnatural in some sentences:

I am confused by this discrepancy when applying the rules, why is it natural in some sentences and unnatural in others, when the definition says it's the same as から判断すると?

> 1. 彼の態度**では**、きっと仕事を辞めると思います。Unnatural
> 2. 彼の態度**から判断すると**、きっと仕事を辞めると思います。Natural

```
Judging from his behavior, I am quite sure that he will quit his job.
```

> 1. 雨**では**中止になる Natural
> 2. 雨**から判断すると**中止になる Unnatural

```
Judging from the rain it (some activity) will be called off. (from the コトバンク example)
```

> 1. 彼の、今のコンディション**では**、優勝はできないかも知れないな。 Natural
> 2. 彼の、今のコンディション**から判断すると**、優勝はできないかも知れないな。 Natural

```
Judging from his current condition, he will not win.
```

---

I can't seem to find much explanation for these uses online, if there are better resources that provide a more detailed explanation, please let me know.

Comment: Did you make a mistake saying 彼の態度では is unnatural? Sometimes things aren't 100% interchangeable, stuff like から判断すると is just there to give you an idea of what the word being defined means. It doesn't mean you can swap them with each other in every case. There's also the thing about some speech patterns sounding like they belong on the news/in literature and not everyday speech. Some phrases are preferred over others when talking about certain things. では is a very fun, useful phrase. I suggest you instead check out Wiktionary's explanations of the term.

Comment: I recommend looking at the 日本語文型辞典's entries for ては (p.276) and では1 (p.278). These seems to pull out some of the different uses, and gives at least a good over view of why they're different. For example, I noticed that the weblio entry seems to conflate the [Vて + は] and [で(particle) + は] formation, which both look like では, and this might be a source of confusion. (Page numbers are from the English translation published in 2015.)